# Django - email fields not listed after the call of .super().clean()

Tags: python, django, validation, email-validation

I'm new to Django and my apologies if this is to basic question (or mistake), but I'm having issues with email format validation when the email is typed like: **test@com**.

I created the form.py and views.py below for test:

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

class userForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(label="First name")
    lname = forms.CharField(label="Last name")
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    vemail = forms.EmailField(label="Email validation")


    def clean(self):
        all_clean_data = super().clean()
        fname = all_clean_data['fname'].lower().capitalize()
        lname = all_clean_data['lname'].lower().capitalize()
        email = all_clean_data['email'].lower()
        vmail = all_clean_data['vemail'].lower()
        if email != vmail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email address doesn't match, please try again")
```

**views.py**

```
def users(request):
    form = forms.userForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.userForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Validation ok')
    return render(request,"test_app/users.html",{'formName':form})
```

Seems that everything is working fine ... but ... if in the form (webpage) I type an email address like: **test@com** and submit the form, 2 things happens:

1. I do not get an alert like "Invalid email format" on the form
   (webpage)
2. The email "key" on all_clean_data['email'] does not
   exists.

If I type a valid email like: test@test.com, it works.
If I type an invalid email address like: abcde, then I get an alert message.

The issue is when I type things like: **test@com** ... then I do not get any validation error message, the submit is triggered but also I do not get the field either.

Appreciate your help.

**Below the debug info**

```
KeyError at /
'email'
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.0.3
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    
'email'
Exception Location:     /Users/.../test_app/forms.py in clean, line 20
Python Executable:  /Users/.../bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/.../test_project/test_project',
 '/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8',
 '/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```